# Alterar o conteúdo de uma DIV vindo de outro site

Tags: javascript, html, html5, jade

Boa tarde,

Estou com uma dificuldade em encontrar um meio de fazer duas divs se comunicarem e preciso de ajuda para saber o que eu posso está usando para fazer essa comunicação

Por exemplo: Um object vai mandar um comando do site2 e vai alterar uma url dentro de uma div no site1, pois o objetivo é que eu possa abrir vários links dentro daquela div sem atualizar a página

Devo ter procurado errado, mas não encontrei uma ferramenta que possa fazer essa conexão onde o site2 manda o comando e o site1 executa

Comment: Você não consegue realizar comandos entre dominios diferentes.
O que você pode fazer é carregar todo conteudo html do site e trabalhar com ele no seu outro site local.

Comment: entendo, eu tinha visto em algum lugar que existem ferramentas que permitem comunicação entre eles, assim um apenas manda o comando e o receptor ao receber esse comando, muda o conteúdo de uma div por exemplo

Answer (score 0):

tudo bem?

Não tem um jeito "fácil" de fazer isso, mas você pode criar um endpoint em seu servidor que o faça, utilizando um controller e Angular/jQuery, por exemplo.

Como você não especificou linguagens/servidor/banco de dados, etc., eu vou dar um exemplo genérico.

Vamos supor que o controller que popula seu html inicialmente simplesmente pegue os dados da tabela "objetos" do banco de dados e retorne para a tela.

Você deve criar um outro controller em seu projeto, que receba dados (geralmente em json). 
Então o outro projeto deve enviar uma requisição para este controller com os dados que você quer adicionar. Pegue esses dados, e grave na tabela "objetos" - isso fará com que o primeiro controller (que popula seu html) possa ver futuramente estes dados.

Assim, basta que a outra aplicação faça uma requisição em seu novo controller para que seja capaz de atualizar a tela. O problema aqui é que ela só muda se ocorrer um recarregamento na página.

Se você ainda deseja que não seja necessário atualizar a página, você pode usar o jQuery ou angular para fazer uma requisição http no seu controller que popula a tela e "repopular" a tela, sem recarregamentos.

um exemplo com jquery seria:

```
$.get('/populaDados', function (response) {
    $(body).html(response); //aqui você deve tratar a resposta para repopular a tela.
});
```

Isso é só um exemplo, você pode criar o controller e usar o objeto no jQuery como quiser.

**ATENÇÂO**
Se o projeto que envia os dados estiver em um domínio diferente, você deve adicionar o header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" na requisição por causa do Cross Origin.

Mais sobre o Cross Origin: [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Acho que isso pode me ajudar, vou estudar a respeito do conteúdo que me passou, obrigado, mais tarde eu volto e comento melhor